# Compare Action<T>

Tags: c#, tdd

I have a service class as below:

```
public class MyService
{
    private readonly IMyDependency _myDependency;

    public MyService(IMyDependency myDependency)
    {
       _myDependency = myDependency;
    }

    public void MyHandler(string param)
    {
       // work
    }

    public void AnotherMethod()
    {
       _myDependency.DoWork(MyHandler);
    }
}
```

How can I Unit Test that MyHandler has been given as a parameter of DoWork()?

Comment: Are you using any mocking library?

Comment: yes, I'm using Moq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Moq, you can write test like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void DoWorkWasCalledWithCorrectParameters()
{
    var mock = new Moq.Mock<IMyDependency>();
    var myService = new MyService(mock.Object);
    myService.AnotherMethod();
    // verify that method was called once and with correct parameter:
    mock.Verify(x => x.DoWork(myService.MyHandler), Moq.Times.Once);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help.